# Generating a dot plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have 3 vectors of data in R and would like to produce a plot like the one here:
!(http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/file/n2134530/Rplot_dotplot.jpg)

For example, say I have the vectors:

```
A=runif(50)
B=runif(50)
C=runif(50)
```

Is there a way for me to produce a plot like the one in the picture? With only three labels on the x-axis (A,B,C) and the values going up as dots in a straight line?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?  So far it looks like you're asking us to write the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw that kind of plot with the normal plot function, just make appropriate x-values for example like this:

```
A<-runif(50)
B<-runif(50)
C<-runif(50)

x<-rep(1:3,each=50) #generate x-coordinates
plot(x,y=c(A,B,C),xaxt="n",xlab="Groups",ylab="Values")
axis(side=1,at=1:3,labels=c("A","B","C"))
```

Or you can use `stripchart` function:

```
#This needs list or data.frame as an input
stripchart(data.frame(A,B,C),vertical=TRUE,pch=1,xlab="Groups",ylab="Values")
```

Comment: Also, use `jitter(x,amount=0.1)` instead of just `x` within `plot` so that you have the jitter effect. Change `amount` to whatever suits you. For the horizontal dotted line, you can use `abline(h=1.0)`